# Error: Type Assertion error JSX element 'string' has no corresponding closing tag

Tags: javascript, typescript, mern

I am trying to learn type assertion in typescript.

```js
let sname:any = "aabiskar";
let longnumber:number = (<string>sname).length
console.log("this is length ",longnumber)
```

[image: This is my screenshot of my code and error]

The compiler is giving me this error:

> JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.
>
> Cannot find name 'React'.
>
> JSX element 'string' has no corresponding closing tag.
>
> '</' expected.
> How to fix this
> #Typescript

I have to tried to fix the code but it is saying "'</' expected".

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [TypeScript Deep Dive - Type Assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#as-foo-vs.-less-than-foo-greater-than):

> **`as foo` vs. `<foo>`**
>
> Originally the syntax that was added was `<foo>`. This is demonstrated below:
>
> ```js
> var foo: any;
> var bar = <string> foo; // bar is now of type "string"
> ```
>
> However, there is an ambiguity in the language grammar when using `<foo>` >style assertions in JSX:
>
> ```
> var foo = <string>bar;
> </string>
> ```
>
> Therefore it is now recommended that you just use `as foo` for consistency.

So following that recommendation you could use this:

```js
let sname: any = "aabiskar";
let longnumber: number = (sname as string).length
console.log("this is length ",longnumber)
```

In case you do not know what JSX is, here an excerpt from the [Wikipedia - JSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSX_(JavaScript)):

> JSX (JavaScript XML) formally (JavaScript Syntax eXtension) is a JavaScript extension that allows creation of DOM trees using an XML-like syntax.

Further resources:

- [JSX Specification by Facebook](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/)
- [Wikipedia - React: basic usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(software)#Basic_usage)

Answer (score 0):

It's taking your 'string' as a jsx element so the compiler is searching for react and asking you to close the 'string' since jsx is the way to put html in your js file. Instead you can do this:

```
let sname:string = 'something'
let longnumber:number = sname.length
console.log('this is ', longnumber)
```

or if you are trying to assign type as 'string' do 'as string' so the compiler doesn't get confused

```
let sname:any = 'something'
let longnumber:number = (sname as string).length
console.log('this is ', longnumber)
```